# Releasing memory allocated with Image.load method in MFC

Tags: mfc

In MFC I'm loading a .PNG image and thereafter, I'm displaying it with a static control as below:

```
CImage Img;
Img.Load(_T(abc.png"));
CBitMap Bmp;
Bmp.Attach(Img.Detach());
CStatic dispImg;
dispImg.SetBitmap(Bmp);
```

In this way I've several images which I'm displaying with the static control repetitively
which is causing significant memory leak within my application. I found several clues by googling, but I couldn't decide the best option for releasing memory. Could anybody please guide me with the best approach.

Comment: I don't see a memory leak in your code snippet. Give an sscce please.

Comment: Please consider the code snippet is within a loop because I'm loading different images based on some events. However, only static control object dispImg with which I'm displaying the image is declared out side the loop. Practically I've seen with every iteration of the loop increases consumed memory by 4KB.

Comment: If the code you show is different from the code you have (for example regarding object life time), how do you expect us to help then? Therefor, as said, sscce please.

Comment: Sorry! I cannot show everything here. Just I given a sample to show you what I wanted to do. Only thing dispImg will be out side the loop. Other things are as I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This code is incomplete. Using a CStatic in this way will never work. It isn't created.
   If you realy want help that macthes your question give a more detailed description.
2. When you use CStatic::SetBitmap ypu must free the HBITMAP handle that is returned by the function. Just read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782(v=vs.85).aspx). So if you use this samne CStatic in a Loop and always assign a new Bitmap to the CStatic this may cause a leak.

Comment: In my project I took one Static control and declared a member variable dispImg for setting different png images based on different events.The same dispImg is being used to display different images at different time within the life cycle of the application. By mistake I said dispImg is within the loop ; actually in a method I'm loading different images(one at a time based on state of some device)through CImage and getting CBitMap object to set it with dispImg.The method is called when an event occurs. As I understood freeing HBITMAP returned by SetBitmap every time won't leave any memory leak.

Comment: You must free the bitmap that is returned by SetBitmap. It would be helpful if you describe the problems in a more detailed way, when you ask the question.

Comment: Thanks xMRI for the help. I'll apply your suggestion and come back.

Answer (score 0):

As xMRi suggested I'm freeing HBITMAP handle returned by CStatic::SetBitmap. In my test app there is a CStatic control member m_pic, a method ChangePic which sets a Bitmap and a button control for changing the image based on a value of a boolean variable SetBlueImg. Defination of ChangePic as below:

```
void CPNGTestDlg::ChangePic(Cstring img)
{
CImage Img;
Img.Load(img);
CBitmap Bmp;
Bmp.Attach(Img.Detach());
HBITMAP hBmp=m_pic.SEtBitmap(Bmp);
if(hBmp!=NULL) DeleteObject(hBmp);
}
```

Click event of the button is defined as below:

```
void CPNGTest::OnBnClickedChngPic()
{
if(SetBlueImg)
{
ChangePic(_T("Blue.png"));
SetBlueImg=false;
}
else
{
ChangePic(_T("Red.png"));
SetBlueImg=true;
}
}
```

Initial value of SetBlueImg=true and in OnInitDialog() I called ChangePic(_T("Red.png"));

I ran the application and continuously clicking the button to change current image but still I can see memory leaks through windows task manager. Hike of memory is by 4KB after clicking button 40/50 times or sometimes unpredictably. Please, point out where I'm missing something which is causing the leaks.

Comment: In the way as xMRi suggested, I'm replacing PNG images with older one but images are overlapping. I've attached a PNG image on the background, then displayed another PNG image on the background, now when I'm trying to replace the second image with a smaller image, third image is getting displayed on the 2nd image. I want to display only the third image on the background. Can any body please suggest me a way ?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of overlapped images when replacing one image on a Static Control with another one, I initially followed the steps below:

1. ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)
2. SetBitmap()
3. ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)

but I didn't know whether this is a correct way to solve the image overlapping. I searched a bit by googling and found the following way:

1. Copying area on the parent window behind the static control before it is drawn for the first time.
2. Copying the image back to the parent every time the static control needs to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

The HBITMAP object has to be deleted when the dialog is destroyed.

```
void CMFCAppDlg::OnDestroy()
{
CDialogEx::OnDestroy();
DeleteObject(m_pic.GetBitmap());
}
```